# Firebase Functions - NodeJS: Asynchronious Array handling

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I´ve checked numerous posts but could not solve the issue.
I want to return the array before going on. I tried using a function with a callback but that did not work either.

My code looks as following:

```
exports.GetHelmets = functions.database.ref('onTrack/{userID}').onCreate(event => {
var helmets = [];

let userID = event.params.userID;

let friendRef = admin.database().ref("friends").child(userID);
friendRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot2){
        let rider = snapshot2.val();
        let riderID = rider.id;

        let rhRef = admin.database().ref("User").child(riderID);
        rhRef.once("value", function(snapshot3){

            let rider2 = snapshot3.val();
            let helmetID = rider2.helmet;

        if (helmetID != "STANDARD"){
            if(helmets.indexOf(helmetID) < 0){
                helmets.push(helmetID);
            };
        };
    });
});
    return helmets;
}).then(helmets => {

    //WORK WITH ARRAY
});
```

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the last `then()` to get all the inner data, each of which requires its own call to `once()`. In such a case, you'll want to use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the `once`s.

```
exports.GetHelmets = functions.database.ref('onTrack/{userID}').onCreate(event => {
let userID = event.params.userID;

let friendRef = admin.database().ref("friends").child(userID);
friendRef.once("value").then(snapshot => {
    var promises = []l
    snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot2){
        let rider = snapshot2.val();
        let riderID = rider.id;

        let rhRef = admin.database().ref("User").child(riderID);
        promises.push(rhRef.once("value");
      });
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
}).then(snapshots => {
    var helmets = [];

    snapshots.forEach((snapshot) => {
        let rider2 = snapshot.val();
        let helmetID = rider2.helmet;

        if (helmetID != "STANDARD"){
          if(helmets.indexOf(helmetID) < 0){
            helmets.push(helmetID);
          };
        };
    });
    // WORK WITH helmets
});
```